# Can't install condrod in Rust on Linux

Tags: linux, rust

I installed freetype but its still not working. I'm using Ubuntu 14.10.

The error is:

```
unresolved import `std::io::timer::sleep`. Could not find `io` in `std`
use std::io::timer::sleep;
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

([full log here](http://pastebin.com/sBnAdeax))

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To get better quality answers, you should strive to make high-quality questions. In this example, including the pertinent parts of your errors here, and stating your Rust version would go a long way to helping us help you!

Answer (score 1):

Rust is currently in an alpha version, working hard on releasing 1.0. Currently, a lot of things are in flux, and APIs may disappear with little to no warning.

In this case, [the current `io` namespace has been renamed to `old_io`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/21543):

> In preparation for the I/O rejuvination of the standard library, this commit
>   renames the current io module to old_io in order to make room for the new
>   I/O modules. It is expected that the I/O RFCs will land incrementally over time
>   instead of all at once, and this provides a fresh clean path for new modules to
>   enter into as well as guaranteeing that all old infrastructure will remain in
>   place for some time.
>
> As each old_io module is replaced it will be deprecated in-place for new
>   structures in std::{io, fs, net} (as appropriate).

As a workaround until the parts of `std::io` are available, you can change references of `std::io` to `std::old_io`.